# Get listed files with .PDF of raw folder in resuorce

Tags: android

How to show a list of all PDF files stored in assets folder or Raw folder in resource folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file object with your path to raw folder then 
call

```
file.listFiles();
```

this will return list of all files then filter these files with .pdf extension

// edited

```
AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets();
String[] arrData = assetManager.list("pdfFolder");//name of your directory as assets/pdfFolder/abc.pdf
List<String> pdfList = new ArrayList<String>();
int size =  arrData.length();
for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
{
   if(arrData[i].contains(".pdf"))

   {
     pdfList.add(arrData[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/best-way-to-read-programming-technical-math-pdfs-on-android-device

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/3831019/…                                                                am not getting what path should i give?                                                                as i want read that PDF file which is listed from assets folder??

Comment: file:///android_asset/pdfFolder

Comment: it is not working :(                                                                     I had written like this:                                          File file = new File("file:///android_asset/raw/"+filename);

Comment: do one thing create a new question for this

Comment: i had created with "Read .PDF/.TXT files in android"

Comment: AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("myfile.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());

Comment: i think we should move this discussion to chat

Comment: ohhhh you dont have enough rep so we cant talk on stack overflow give me request on my mail id which is in my stack overflow profile